# Cannot ES6 import JSX modules in Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

For some reason I can't seem to get Webpack to import modules from .JSX files. Every time I try to run Webpack I'll get this message:

```
ERROR in ./src/Example.jsx
Module parse failed: /path/to/project/src/Example.jsx Unexpected token (6:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:12)
```

The thing is; there isn't a whole lot in ./src/Example.jsx. In fact this is all that it contains:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Example extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (<h2>Hello world!!</h2>);
  }
};
```

Webpack did not have any issues when I had the class in my index.jsx file but when I moved it to its own file webpack all of a sudden couldn figure out what to do. I've tried to resolve this by using [babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/) but that didn't seem to solve my problem. What do I need to do to get Webpack to properly convert/parse .JSX files?

**/* package.json */**

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "webpack": "1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.2.2",
    "jest-cli": "^13.2.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --port 9999",
    "start": "npm run build && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999",
    "test": "jest --verbose --coverage --config jest.config.json"
  }
}
```

**/* webpack.config.js */**

```
var path    = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var BUILD_DIR  = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/');
var SOURCE_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

module.exports = {
  entry: SOURCE_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /[^\.spec]+\.jsx$/,
        include: SOURCE_DIR,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**/* .baberc */**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

**/* src/index.jsx */**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Example from './Example'


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('floor-plan'));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got your setup working with these few modifications. I isolated the problem to your test property.

```
var path    = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var BUILD_DIR  = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/');
var SOURCE_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

module.exports = {
  entry: SOURCE_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: SOURCE_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        },
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped

Comment: `configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should be an non-empty string.`

Answer (score 4):

The reason could be 
`import Example from './Example'` in `index.jsx`

webpack will treat this as `js` import instead of `jsx`.

try

`import Example from './Example.jsx'`

Comment: While this works, it is still undesirable to explicitly mention the file extension. The build-process should automagically handle such things